# False boxing warning using C# Generics?

Tags: c#, generics, reference, boxing

I am trying to implement `Equals` from `IEqualityComparer<T>`, where if T is a reference type, `ReferenceEquals` is returned, and if T is a value type, `Equals` is returned.

So I tried doing this :

```
public bool Equals(T x, T y) {
    if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
        return Equals(x, y);

    return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
}
```

My reasoning is, if `x` and `y` are not value types, then they must be reference types, so `ReferenceEquals` should not be boxing anything.

But I get this warning :

**Boxing allocation: conversion from value type 'T' to reference type 'object'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a boxing applied *if* `T` is not a class. Since the methods most likely call for an `object` (and specifically `ReferenceEquals` does), there is some boxing required to call those methods. (And by the way, you are recursively calling `Equals` now.)

The warning will disappear if you use the `class` constraint (but obviously, it doesn't exactly match the possibilities of your current class):

```
public class X<T> where T : class
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y) {
        if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            return Equals(x, y);

        return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }
}
```